# Do Redis images currently work with Docker on Windows?

Tags: redis, docker-for-windows

I am running Docker with Linux containers. When I try to do a Redis pull I get "docker: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries." I have seen many tutorials showing redis running on docker windows. Has something changed with later versions of redis which means that it no longer works with docker on Windows?

Comment: docker is docker. if it runs, it runs. that's part of it's design.

Comment: So Redis should currently work on windows within a Linux Container? This is Windows Server 2016 essentials

Comment: it would not be docker if it would not be able to run docker containers.

Comment: As I said, I am getting "docker: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries" when I try to pull. I'm just trying to work out why this is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start dockerd.exe with the --experimental flag and your problem will be solved.

easy find on google:

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1100

https://blog.docker.com/2017/09/preview-linux-containers-on-windows/

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well. Did not work. Im running under in linux container mode and its showing OS/Arch: windows/amd64 when i try "docker version". Is this right?

Comment: The problem seems to be that I was running this on Windows Server 2016 essentials which as I discovered, does not allow containers. So the suggestion Gottz made would not work for me.